# Why is the default function being invoked when there is no explicit call?

Tags: java, groovy

I have created 2 methods

Method 1 - customConversion - with just 2 parameters

Method 2 - defaultConversion - with 2 parameters (one with default value)

I have a scenario wherein only method:customConversion is being invoked explicitly by the code, but i find in the output that the method:defaultConversion is also being invoked

I am unable to arrive at a conclusion as for how the method:defaultConversion is being invoked?

```
class Conversion{

    public def customConversion(int price, int rate){
        println "customConversion -> Price ->"+price+"Rate ->"+rate;
        double result = (rate*price);
        println "The amount is "+result;
    }

    public def defaultConversion(int price,int rate=60){
        println "defaultConversion -> Price ->"+price+"Rate ->"+rate;
        double result = (rate*price);
        println "The amount is "+result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double result = 0;

        Conversion c = new Conversion();

        println "Enter the price:";
        int price = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        println "1.Custom Conversion\n2.Default Conversion\nEnter the choice:"
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
            println "Enter the conversion rate:";
            int rate = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            c.customConversion(price,rate);

            case 2:
            c.defaultConversion(price);
        }//End of switch

    }//End of main
}//End of class
```

Input: 
200
1
45

```
Actual Output:
Enter the price:
1.Custom Conversion
2.Default Conversion
Enter the choice:
Enter the conversion rate:
customConversion -> Price ->200Rate ->45
The amount is 9000.0
defaultConversion -> Price ->200Rate ->60
The amount is 12000.0

Expected Output:
Enter the price:
1.Custom Conversion
2.Default Conversion
Enter the choice:
Enter the conversion rate:
customConversion -> Price ->200Rate ->45
The amount is 9000.0
```

Comment: Add a `break` statement at the end of each switch case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't write a `break` at the end of case, try adding `break;` after each case :

```
switch(choice){
            case 1:
            println "Enter the conversion rate:";
            int rate = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            c.customConversion(price,rate);
            break; 

            case 2:
            c.defaultConversion(price);
            break; 
        }//End of switch
```

Here's the [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp) which explains in a small paragraph why to add the `break` keyword in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks much ! how did i miss to add a break statement !

Comment: @Sarronya your welcome, aslo it would be appreciated if you could mark my answer as the correct one :)